# OpenGL Framebuffer Object issue

Tags: opengl, rendering, frame-buffer, fbo

I am struggling with implementing a proper Framebuffer Object .

glCheckFramebufferStatus is returning me:
 GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT (36054).

What am i missing?

```
GLuint fbo, rboColor, rboDepth;

// Color renderbuffer.
glGenRenderbuffers(1,&rboColor);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,rboColor);
// Set storage for currently bound renderbuffer.
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_BGRA, _w, _h);

// Depth renderbuffer
glGenRenderbuffers(1,&rboDepth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,rboDepth);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, _w, _h);

// Framebuffer
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,     GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboColor);
// Set renderbuffers for currently bound framebuffer
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_RENDERBUFFER,rboDepth);

 // Set to write to the framebuffer.
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);

// Tell glReadPixels where to read from.
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

GLenum e = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);//glCheckFramebufferStatus: check the completeness status of a framebuffer
if (e != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
printf("\nThere is a problem with the FBO.");

}
```

Comment: Have you check [this page](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness) to see if your framebuffer is complete?

Comment: Check errors after every glCall... I suspect one of them may be failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing I would do is to figure out if any previous call to `glCheckFramebufferStatus` has failed. You are not calling [`glGetError`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetError.xml) at any point, which means you are probably missing a previous error that could help you figure out the problem. Make sure to add an error check after every previous GL call and log any error encountered. That will narrow down your search to the offending function.

That said, it is very likely that your renderbuffer allocations are failing. Probably the formats `GL_BGRA` or `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` are not supported in the platform. If this is OpenGL-ES code, [look in here](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRenderbufferStorage.xml) to see the supported color and depth formats. This is kind of obvious, but also make sure the width and height are `> 0`!

**GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT** is generated when:

> Not all framebuffer attachment points are framebuffer attachment
>   complete. This means that at least one attachment point with a
>   renderbuffer or texture attached has its attached object no longer in
>   existence or has an attached image with a width or height of zero, or
>   the color attachment point has a non-color-renderable image attached,
>   or the depth attachment point has a non-depth-renderable image
>   attached, or the stencil attachment point has a non-stencil-renderable
>   image attached.

([source](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml))

Comment: I'm also wondering what version of OpenGL you are using. If it is -ES, then the target would be GL_FRAMEBUFFER (not GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER), according to https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFramebufferRenderbuffer.xml.

Yes, check errors.

Comment: The fault was with the GL_BGRA.
Thanks guys.